# Wrong City returned when specifying a District in geocode request

Tags: here-api

I am working with HERE geocoder and found a case where the city returned is wrong if we add a particular district name in the searchtext parameter.

This is the example request:

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=...&app_code=...&searchtext=Centro,Campos%20dos%20Goytacazes,RJ,Brazil
```

And this is the significant parts of the response:

```
{
  _type: "SearchResultsViewType",
  ViewId: 0,
  Result: [
    {
      Relevance: 1,
      MatchLevel: "district",
      MatchQuality: {
         Country: 1,
         State: 1,
         City: 1,
         District: 1
     },
     Location: {
                 ...
                 Address: {
                     Label: "Centro, Nova Iguaçu, RJ, Brasil",
                     Country: "BRA",
                     State: "RJ",
                     City: "Nova Iguaçu",
                     District: "Centro",
                     PostalCode: "26052-060",
                     ...
     }
```

As you can see, the MatchQuality.City is 1, but the City returned is wrong ("Nova Iguaçu" instead of "Campos dos Goytacazes").

It seems the district "Centro" is being taken from another city, but the matchQuality says the city matched correctly (!)

Trying the same request without the district name returns the correct city in the Address:

Request:

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=...&app_code=...&searchtext=Campos%20dos%20Goytacazes,RJ,Brazil
```

Response:

```
{
  _type: "SearchResultsViewType",
  ViewId: 0,
  Result: [
    {
      Relevance: 1,
      MatchLevel: "city",
      MatchQuality: {
         Country: 1,
         State: 1,
         City: 1
     },
     Location: {
                 ...
                 Address: {
                             Label: "Campos dos Goytacazes, RJ, Brasil",
                             Country: "BRA",
                             State: "RJ",
                             City: "Campos dos Goytacazes",
                             PostalCode: "28010-550",
                             ...
                          }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The matchLevel clearly states for the first request as 'district' which means it exactly matched 'Centro' as a district and fetch the details of that district(the city, country etc it belongs to).

searchtext request attribute is a free form text and matchquality in the response doesn't provide the quality of the values provided in it. Matchquality returns 1 for country,state and city since they have matched them exactly for the Centro district.

If you need matchquality to exactly say the relevance for the city you have provided then you should explicitly mention city attribute in the request.

See https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-geocode.html for the entire list of request attributes possible.

Hope this helps!

> city
>
> xs:string A country specific mapping is required. Example,
>
> ```
> USA: City
> Germany: Gemeinde
> ```
>
> country
>
> xs:string, exact match Specify the country or list of countries using
>   the country code (3 bytes, ISO 3166-1-alpha-3) or the country name.
>   This is a strict filter. Results are restricted to the specified
>   country or countries.
>
> Note: To avoid ambiguity we recommend to specify the country with the
>   3-letter ISO code and not with the spelled out country name. With
>   names there is a higher risk of misspells and also not all language
>   translations for all countries are supported.

Comment: Thanks, I added another answer because I needed to give you more examples... could you take a look at it please? Thanks!